# Rails-jQuery. How do I reset the form after submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been Googling but I cannot find any solutions.
How do I reset the form, clear the input of my field after submit?

When I click "Submit" with the correct input/email, the form got reset and the 'POST' action is called but it looks like the form was reset before the 'POST' action, which means I've submitted nothing. How do I clear the input, reset the form and actually submit the input?

Please check below my `users.js`, `users_controller.rb`, `new.html.erb`
Thanks in advance.

**users.js**

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
  var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
  return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};

$(function () {
  $("form").submit(function (event) {
      var email = $("input#user_email").val();
      if (email == "") {
        $(".subscribe-message").html('<i class="fa fa-warning"></i> You must enter a valid email address.').show();
      } 
      else if (!isValidEmailAddress( email )) {
        $(".subscribe-message").html('<i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Email address is not valid').show();
      }
      else {
        $(".subscribe-message").html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> We will be in touch soon!').show();
        $("form")[0].reset();
          }
   });
});
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user, remote: true do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit :Submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
<div></div>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to '/' }
      format.js
      end   
    @user.save
  end

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually POST the data first. Check out jQuery's `$.post()` function. In the callback, you can then change the success/error message.

Example:

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
  var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
  return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};

$("#form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // handle the post ourselves

  var $form = $(this),
      email = $("input#user_email").val();

  if (email == "") {
    $(".subscribe-message").html('<i class="fa fa-warning"></i> You must enter a valid email address.').show();
    return false;
  } 
  else if (!isValidEmailAddress( email )) {
    $(".subscribe-message").html('<i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Email address is not valid').show();
    return false;
  }

  $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize(), function(response) {
    if(response.status == 'OK') { // assuming there is a "status" object in response in JSON format
      $(".lj-subscribe-message").html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> We will be in touch soon!').show();
      $("form")[0].reset();
    } else {
      $(".subscribe-message").html('<i class="fa fa-warning"></i>' + response.status).show();
    }
  }, "json"); // make sure the response TYPE matches here
});
```

The only thing you need now is something to handle the POST-ed data and output the results in JSON format.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Sorry, I'm kind of a newbie, I have no idea how to do that JSON, do I need to add `format.json` in my users_controller.rb ?

Comment: Sorry, I won't be able to help with that. JSON is just a format of text.